Trouble understanding DC3 algorithm
The paper i am going through: https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/tpkarkka/publications/jacm05-revised.pdf
I think its the same question as Suffix array DC3 algorithm, but since I am unable to access the link posted there, and also the answers on that post didn't satisfy my query, therefore Ill ask here.
I don't understand the following step on page 6:

Example. R = [abb][ada][bba][do0][bba][dab][bad][o00].
suffixes of R, first radix sort the characters of R and rename them
with their ranks to obtain the string R0 . If all characters are
different, the order of characters gives directly the order of
suffixes. Otherwise, sort the suffixes of R0 using Algorithm DC3.
Example. R0 = (1, 2, 4, 6, 4, 5, 3, 7) and SAR0 = (8, 0, 1, 6, 4, 2,
5, 3, 7).

After radix sorting R, we get:
Sorted R = [abb][ada][bad][bba][bba][dab][do0][o00].
if we order by 1 based indexing, then the R0 = [1,2,7,3,5,6,4,8] because:
R[1] = abb, R[2] = ada, R[7] = bad ... so on
if we order it based on 0 based index, its still not equal to whats shown in example.
Can anyone please help me understand how R0, and then how SAR0 was obtained in the paper.

I UNDERSTAND NOW,
For anyone with the same confusion
I miunderstood the para, from sorted R, you get the ranks, and then you replace the triplets in R, with the ranks
Example:
Sorted R and its rank:
[abb] -> 1
[ada] -> 2
[bad] -> 3
[bba] , [bba] -> 4
[dab] -> 5
[do0] -> 6
[0oo] -> 7
Now we use this rank to replace the triplets in R 
R0 = [1,2,4,6,4,5,3,7]
